# Microsoft Edge instance of Element does not return same as chrome/firefox

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I am using ResizeObserver library and when trying to debug MS Edge i noticed that the problem lies in Edge returning false to

```
(el instanceof Element)
```

while every other browser say its true.

Maybe someone could explain me reasons why this is happening?

Comment: Just to check - what is `el`? I assume an HTML element but not sure what it is. I'll try to replicate this.

Comment: my Edge installation shows `true` for an element. Just not for `document`, but that's the same for all browsers. You should figure out if a different `el` is used per browser

Comment: @VLAZ It is backbone view `el` attribute. In this case it is `div` element

Comment: [I can't reproduce it](https://jsbin.com/dozepoqapo/edit?html,js,console) - both Firefox and Edge give me `true`

Comment: Please explain more details about your problem, about the ResizeObserver and your code. From [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver), it seems that the ResizeObserver not supported Edge browser.